# Vue is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to build a demo app with Vue.js. What I am getting is an odd error that Vue is not defined.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Vue JS Intro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
        <input v-model="message">
    </div>

    <script type="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var demo = new Vue({
            el: '#demo',
            data: {
                message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I miss here? This is not a CDN issue as I also downloaded the library from the official website, used it and got the same result

> index.html:15 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined

Answer (score 50, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qutoco/edit?html,css,console,output)***

1. You missed the order, first goes:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
```

and then:

```
<script>
    var demo = new Vue({
        el: '#demo',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
        }
    });
</script>
```

2. And `type="JavaScript"` should be `type="text/javascript"` (or rather nothing at all)

Comment: That's a valid point, I swapped them around and updated my question wth the new code. The problem is still there

Comment: @VladimirHraban remove `type="JavaScript"`

Comment: I was using https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue from https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/. Using your url seemed to remove my error, but the message still isn't replaced here :(

Comment: Also putting the js cdn include within the head tag fixes the problem for me

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes the problem may be if you `import` that like this:

```
const Vue = window.vue;
```

this may overwrite the original `Vue` reference.

Answer (score 3):

try to fix `type="JavaScript"` to `type="text/javascript"` in you vue.js srcipt tag, or just remove it. 
Modern browsers will take script tag as javascript as default.

Answer (score 3):

as extra information,
if you use VueJs version ^3.2.0 and up, the way you should write Vueis is different witch you have the app.js has this code:

```
import "./bootstrap";
import { createApp } from "vue";

 const app = createApp({});
```

So you have to use app object instead of Vue as you see bellow

```
import VueCountdownTimer from "vuejs-countdown-timer";
app.use(VueCountdownTimer);
```

I shared this information because this error counted me.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the script below to index.html inside the HEAD tag.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

But in your case, since you don't have index.html, just add it to your HEAD tag instead.

So it's like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error but as undefined due to the way I included js files

Initailly i had

```
<script src="~/vue/blade-account-update-credit-card-vue.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/lib/vue/vue_v2.5.16.js"></script>
```

in the end of my .cshtml page 
GOT Error  **Vue not Defined**
but later I changed it to

```
<script src="~/lib/vue/vue_v2.5.16.js"></script> 
<script src="~/vue/blade-account-update-credit-card-vue.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

and magically it worked. So i assume that vue js needs to be loaded on top of the .vue

Answer (score 1):

I found two main problems with that implementation. First, when you import the `vue.js` script you use `type="JavaScript"` as `content-type` which is wrong. You should remove this `type` parameter because by default `script` tags have `text/javascript` as default `content-type`. Or, just replace the `type` parameter with the correct `content-type` which is  `type="text/javascript"`.

The second problem is that your script is embedded in the same HTML file means that it may be triggered first and probably the `vue.js` file was not loaded yet. You can fix this using a **jQuery** snippet `$(function(){ /* ... */ });` or adding a **javascript** function as shown in this example:

```js
// Verifies if the document is ready
function ready(f) {
  /in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('ready(' + f + ')', 9) : f();
}

ready(function() {
  var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>{{message}}</p>
  <input v-model="message">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, using jQuery to load Vue! Very very nice programming approach!

Answer (score 0):

just put `text/javascript` in your script tag which you use for cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for a strange reason, the `js` that contains the `Vue`, has a `defer` inside the `script` definition:

```
<script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
```

That caused the `script` loads asynchronously than the other `js` files.

After I remove the `defer` tag, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing this error in src/main.js file in vue,

just add :-

```
var Vue = require('vue')
```

Then, It will work fine.