# why getting error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined' in desktop notification using laravel vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7, pusher, pusher-js

I have followed the steps mentioned in this link for desktop notification in localhost https://pusher.com/tutorials/desktop-notifications-laravel/. and run the command in cli 'npm run dev'.

[image]

after running the project using command 'php artisan serve' in live link getting the error

[image]

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue'));
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

 mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
     //
 ]).vue();
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     forceTLS: true
     });
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!-- ./resources/views/welcome.blade.php -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- CSRF Token -->
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

  <title>News Talk</title>

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .container {
      padding-top: 100px;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
      'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="app">
    <!-- home Vue component -->
    <home></home>
  </div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.12/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when run the command 'npm run dev'

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
        "vue": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I have added vue.js <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script> cdn link to blade. but front page leaves it blank

Comment: can you put your `bootstrap.js` file code

Comment: @KamleshPaul added in question

Comment: @kumarishwetha First you have add vue js cdn script and add app.js compiled js file in blade file

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar same thing I did. you can see in my question I have added blade file

Comment: @kumarishwetha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210062/vue-is-not-defined 
Check this one. you should get your answer here.

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar I mentioned the issue is here. I have added vue.js <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></…> cdn link to blade. but front page leaves it blank. Now no error

Comment: @KamleshPaul 'npm i vue@2.5.17' gives package mismatch error

Comment: @kumarishwetha please put `package.json` code

Comment: @KamleshPaul posted in question. i installed the same version vue@2.6.12 and  vue-template-compiler@2.6.12. now bulid is successfull.  but getting error  Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

you have missing this `window.Vue = require("vue");` in

#### app.js

```js
window.Vue = require("vue");
require('./bootstrap');
Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue'));
```

put this on your `package.json`

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"

    },
    "dependencies": {
        "laravel-echo": "^1.11.3",
        "pusher-js": "^7.0.3",
        "vue": "^2.6.12"
    }
}
```

then run `npm run update && npm run dev`

Comment: Error : Uncaught TypeError: Vue.component is not a function

Comment: after this change compile you code please `npm run dev`

Comment: compiled but got error

Comment: run `npm i vue@2.6.12` then

Comment: Vue packages version mismatch: got error in 'npm run dev' build is unsuccessfull :(

Comment: posted the error in question. You can check

Comment: run `npm i vue@2.5.17` then

Answer (score 0):

1. First remove `node_modules` folder and package-lock file by running `rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json`.
2. Remove vue dependencies `vue`, `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler` from package.json file.
3. Now run `npm install`.
4. Install `vue` and `vue-loader` by `npm install vue vue-loader file-loader`
5. It will install vue 2.6.13 and vue-loader 15.9.7 and file-loader 6.2.0 version package.
6. Install `npm install vue-template-compiler --save`

In app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('home', require('./components/Home.vue'));
```

*You don't need to add cdn link in blade file. It will automatically added using webpack*

Comment: First remove node_modules folder by running rm -rf node_modules/. can I delete it directly? because I am using windows

Comment: Yes it will work. i'm using that.

Comment: no. leaves blank page

Comment: Have you remove node_modules and package-lock.json ??